# How to build Dynamic SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I’m new to SSIS package.

I need to execute a same stored procedure available in several remote data bases and insert those data into a main database in my office.
I’m trying to create a SSIS package to implement above requirement.        (I used OLE DB Source control and OLE DB Destination control for this) Any way I hope to increase number of remote data bases in future.  Is there any way to do this process rather modify SSIS package each time I add new remote data base to system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the OLE DB Source control and OLE DB Destination control use a connection manager where you inform your connection string, which includes the database name among other things. You can make this property variable using SSIS configurations, so the package will read it from a XML file for example.

Read about config files, it will solve your problem